# OAuth on mobile apps

Tags: oauth, mobile-phones

I want to create an Android application that takes advantage of Facebook and Twitter.  I was planning on using OAuth but the more I think about the less confident I become in this being the best solution.  My concern is with the Consumer Secret key, the one used to authenticate the application.  I can safely store the Access Token's secret key because if that gets compromised the user just needs to reauthenticate and they have a new one;  however, if the consumer secret gets compromised, my application as a whole gets compromised across all devices since it is app, not user, specific.  This is fine for web apps since it is stored on a secure central server, but for mobile apps where it is installed in multiple devices it seems dangerous.  I don't like the idea of having that consumer key sitting on a number of devices just waiting to be compromised.  So, I guess my question is should I be going with OAuth or is there some other better method out there.

Answer (score 0):

We use OAuth without any problems. Also see here:

http://blog.oauth.net/2009/04/22/acknowledgement-of-the-oauth-security-issue/

Comment: Link is dead. Any other suggestions ?